# How to obtain color information from a point cloud and display it? -Qt

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I have a colored pcd file and trying to visualize it with qt. However, when I opened the colored pcd file, I can't see the colors.

[image: PCD File]

Here is my code:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_rgb (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::PointXYZRGB point;

uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(255) << 16 |
            static_cast<uint32_t>(15) << 8 | 
            static_cast<uint32_t>(15));


QString fileName_rgba = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                    "/home",
                                                    tr("Pcd Files (*.pcd)"));

filePath_rgba = fileName_rgba.toStdString();

if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (filePath_rgba, *cloud_rgb) == -1) //* load the file
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }

int pointCount = cloud_rgb->width * cloud_rgb->height;
string pointString = "Loaded " + to_string(pointCount) + " data points from " + fileName_rgba.toStdString() + "with the following fields: ";
QString dum = QString::fromStdString(pointString);
ui->pcdInfo->setText(dum);

pviz.removeAllPointClouds();


vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = pviz.getRenderWindow();
ui->widget_rgba->SetRenderWindow (renderWindow);

pviz.setupInteractor (ui->widget_rgba->GetInteractor (), ui->widget_rgba->GetRenderWindow ());
pviz.getInteractorStyle ()->setKeyboardModifier (pcl::visualization::INTERACTOR_KB_MOD_SHIFT);

pviz.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(cloud_rgb);
pviz.setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0.1);


ui->widget_rgba->show();
```

How can I see the colored version of this pcd file?

Comment: share one row to a point of the pcd file please!

Comment: 2320 2e50 4344 2076 302e 3720 2d20 506f   This is the one row from my pcd file. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: what is pviz???

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what is defining the pcd file. assuming you have a file with a header like this:

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z rgb
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1
```

then rgb means you Do have colors in the point cloud,

> FIELDS x y z **rgb**

the size of the color is 4bytes

> SIZE 4 4 4 **4**

and is represented as a

> float TYPE F F F **F**

so in the data rows, take the last element,

> 66.873619 -91.371956 773.60254 **9.8649324e-039**

and read the bytes R,G,B from it, for example the float 9.8649324e-039 is represented as

```
00000000 01101011 01101011 01101011
  ^-dc     ^         ^        ^  
           |-Red     |-Green  |
                              |-Blue
```

[image]

---

### Update:

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format 
VERSION 0.7 
FIELDS x y z rgba 
label 
SIZE 4 4 4 4 4 
TYPE F F F U U 
COUNT 1 1 1 1 1 
WIDTH 191572 
HEIGHT 1 
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
POINTS 191572 
DATA binary
```

in your case U means unsigned data

> represents unsigned types uint8 (unsigned char), uint16 (unsigned short), uint32 (unsigned int)

so your data

```
2320 2e50 4344 2076 302e 3720 2d20 506f
|---X---|                     |
_________ |---Y---|           |
                    |---Z---| |
                              |--COLOR--|
```

so the color is "**2d20 506f**"

```
2d 20 50 6f 
 ^-r
   ^-g
      ^b
         ^-a
```

so

```
Red = 0x2D
Green = 0x20
Blue = 0x50
Alpha = 0x6F
```

convert those values to int and create a **QColor** :)

Comment: I don't have a header like this.

Comment: what header does your file have??

Comment: Ohh okey find the header. My header look like this but when I try to visualize it, I cant see the colors.

Comment: # .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z rgba label
SIZE 4 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F U U
COUNT 1 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 191572
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 191572
DATA binary

Comment: yes, you cant see the colors because you are ignoring /missreading the data

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I'm really new to this and didn't understand how to implement this to my code. Is there a way to help me about it?